# convert number into customized format

Tags: sql, informatica

i have small requirement i have values with high precision , i need to convert those values into decimals
may be i couldn't able to express my exact requirement but with examples you can understand more better.

Example:

i have a value `8.569494954354` , i need to convert this value into  `0.000000000001`

if i consider n= number of values after decimal,in this case i have `n=12`,so i need `0.(n-1)` zero's(0) and at last value should be one(1)

can anyone please give logic for this requirement, i have to try this logic in variable port in informatica

more examples:

```
7.69594960931 > 0.00000000001
4.424 > 0.001
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the transformation engine in Informatica, but you can do this in MSSql with the following query:

```
select cast(1 as float) / cast(power(10,FLOOR(LOG10(REVERSE(YOUR_NUMBER+1)))+1) as float)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
out_number - POWER(0.1, LENGTH(TO_CHAR(in_number))-2)
```

This should do the trick. The idea is to raise `0.1` to the power of length of your input number decreased by two, to not count the leading number and the decimal point.